# Controlling the movement of text on a parallax website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I am working on a parallax website. The parallax relies on everything being a background image - the images that will move at different speeds.

Is there a way to control text as well, without making it an image? By control I mean fix it in place while the parallax images move? Without fixed positioning it just flys past the images going at the default page speed - which is faster than the parallax.

I have been playing with position:fixed and z-index - which works to a point: http://jsfiddle.net/bf8Zh/1/ . The problem is that everything that everything goes a bit wrong the further down the pages you go - overlapping etc

The above jsfiddle is an example of using the position:fixed/z-index to try and get around the problem.

Example of the css:

```
#intro,
#two,
#three,
#four {width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; height: 800px; overflow: hidden; background-position: 50% 50% !important;}

#intro {background:url(../img/bg_1.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat fixed #000;}
#two {background:url(../img/bg_7.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat fixed; z-index: 25; position: relative;}
#three {background:url(../img/bg_8.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat fixed #ccc; z-index: 9999; position:relative}
#four {background:url(../img/bg_7.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat fixed;}

#two .content {width: 300px; margin: 300px 0 0 200px; float: left; z-index: 50; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0}
#two .content .sectionTitle {font-size: 36px; margin: 10px 0; z-index: 50;}
#two .content .sectionText {font-size: 12px; margin: 10px 0; z-index: 50;}
#two .content .sectionTags {font-size: 12px; margin: 10px 0; z-index: 50;}

#three .content {width: 300px; margin: 300px 200px 0 0; float: right; z-index: 100;}
#three .content .sectionTitle {font-size: 36px; margin: 10px 0; z-index: 100;}
#three .content .sectionText {font-size: 12px; margin: 10px 0; z-index: 100;}
#three .content .sectionTags {font-size: 12px; margin: 10px 0; z-index: 100;}
```

Comment: [Always post *relevant* code and markup **in the question itself**, don't just link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, that seems to work, is using the jQuery inview plugin - http://remysharp.com/downloads/jquery.inview.js

```
$('#seven, #three').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
        if (visible == true) {
            $(this).addClass("active");
        }else{
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        }
    });
```

Using the above code to add an active class to pages once scrolled into view, then hopefully removing the class afterwards. The active class changing the z-index of the pages in question. Seems to work so far - with the text using position:fixed.

```
#three {background:url(../img/bg_grey.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat fixed;height: 2800px; position: relative; z-index: 800;}
#three.active {background:url(../img/bg_grey.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat fixed;height: 2800px; position: relative; z-index: 850;}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to control text speed as well, without making it an image?

You can animate the text at any speed you like. Your fiddle didn't work for me (just a black frame for output), but here's the basic:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#sometext").animate({
          left: "+500"
        },
        500 // This is the duration, in milliseconds
    );
  });
});
```

You can supply the duration the animation should take to the `animate` function.

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/iseqes) | [source](http://jsbin.com/iseqes/edit) - The example varies the time from 250ms through 750ms

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry, I had to edit my question. I am more after trying to secure the text in place - if there is another option than position: fixed and using z-index to hide the text under the next pages. The jsfiddle should work if you scroll down in the window.

Comment: @DBUK: What "speed" do you refer to, then?

Comment: Sorry, my description isn't the greatest. The text moves with the default page speed when the user scrolls, but the images in the parallax move slower and it literally looks like the text just flys by. I can use position:fixed on the text so it stays in place and then with z-index I can hide it behind the pages that follow. The problem is when it comes to text further down the page. Its hurting my head tbh, I guess there probably isn't a solution with HTML/CSS, unless someone knows a CSS trick.